# jQuery POST to CakePHP $this->data

Tags: jquery, post, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to use jQuerys post-function to post a form to a CakePHP-script.

Like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){

   //Code to prevent redirect

   dataString = 'test=testdata';

   $.post('cakephp/forms/output', dataString, function(response){
      alert(response);
   })
});
```

**CakePHP**

```
function output(){
   pr($this->data);                # Print nothing
   pr($_POST);                     # Print test => testdata 
   $this->render('view','ajax');   # Render ajax-friendly
}
```

So `$_POST` isn't empty but `$this->data` is... how come??

The form element i which to post data from is got from aja, if that is something that matters in this case.

Comment: You have mismatched quotes in '$('#submit_btn").click`. Should be `$('#submit_btn').click`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the code above isn't really the code im using, its more of an example, so it didn't solve my problem. :)

Comment: Thought as much which is why it was a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$this->data expects your variable names to be in the form

```
data[Model][Property]
```

For your example change dataString to `data['ModelName']['test']=test data`

and it should work.

Comment: For instance, var data = {'data[User][id]':'1234', 'data[User][name]':'John'};

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the controller's [data attribute](http://book.cakephp.org/view/959/Controller-Attributes#data-972) is only prefilled when the POST data conforms to an existing model attribute, like when data is POSTed via the form helper. So you might have to send "Test.something=testdata", so that you can access $this->data["Test"]["something"] in the controller.