# POST data not appearing in CakePHP controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using AJAX on a knockout.js form to post some information that CakePHP should receive, however, Cake doesn't seem to find anything. Also, the alert isn't appearing despite a 200 status (OK) from the POST.

Here's the AJAX

```
$.ajax({  
          url: "/orders/finalize_payment",  
          type: "POST",  
          dataType: "json",  
          contentType: "json",  
          data: JSON.stringify({"customer": customer_id}),  
          success: function(){              
            alert("success");  
          }
    });
```

Here's the corresponding action in the orders controller. Right now, I completely stripped it to just the bare minimum.

```
function finalize_payment($id = null){
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if($this->request->is('post')){ //the user has submitted which status to view
        print_r($this->request->data);
            echo "test"; //just to make sure it's reaching this point
    }
}
```

When I open up the network tab in chrome, it shows the request payload as

```
customer: 1
```

The POST shows as success, status 200. I checked the response headers and it just shows

```
array
(
)
test
```

Despite chrome showing a payload being sent, CakePHP isn't finding it apparently.

**Update**

I changed the request from AJAX to $.post and it worked. I still have no clue why

```
$.post("/orders/finalize_payment",{"customer_id":customer_id},function(data){
        alert('success');
 });
```

Answer (score 17):

### Don't encode post data as json

The code in the question won't appear in any php script, the reason is this:

> contentType: "json"

It's not a form-url-encoded request, so e.g. the following code:

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

will output:

```
Array()
'{"customer":123}'
```

If you want to submit data as json, you'll need to read the raw request body:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

There might be times when that's desirable (api usage), but that isn't the normal way to use `$.post`.

### The normal way

The normal way to submit data, is to let jQuery take care of encoding things for you:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "/orders/finalize_payment",  
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "json",  // this is optional - indicates the expected response format
    data: {"customer": customer_id},  
    success: function(){              
       alert("success");  
    }
});
```

This will submit the post data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and be available as `$this->request->data` in the controller.

### Why $.post works

> I changed the request from AJAX to $.post and it worked. I still have no clue why

Implicitly with the updated code in the question you have:

- removed the JSON.stringify call
- changed from submitting json  to submitting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

As such, it's not that `$.post` works and `$.ajax` didn't (`$.post` infact just calls `$.ajax`) - it's that the parameters for the resultant `$.ajax` call are correct with the syntax in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using CakePHP you may find adding RequestHandler to your components fixes the problem.

```
public $components = array([snip], 'RequestHandler');
```

Doing this allowed me to transparently access JSON posted data using $this->request->data. The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733300/2964500) answer's advice to not encode POST data as JSON becomes a bit awkward, given that certain JS frameworks, such as Angular, post JSON as default.

Answer (score 2):

Using raw data and json you can use:

```
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
```

**Data is an object now, not an array.

Then you can use:

```
  $this->MyModel->save($data).
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicely formatted question :)

I'm pretty sure I have the answer, though I could be wrong... Basically, `$this->request` is an object in Cake, and `$this->request->data` is a variable/array that's a property of the object.

The data you're sending to Cake is going straight into the object (if this is even possible), not into the `data` array. This is why when Cake generates forms using the HtmlHelper, the names are, for example `data[User][username]`.

I think, if you put `JSON.stringify({"customer": customer_id})` into a `'data'` array and send that, it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by 'into a data array'. I changed it to the following and nothing changed JSON.stringify({"data": [ {"customer": customer_id} ] })

Comment: I think you need to get rid of JSON.stringify and pass the object, i.e: `data: {"customer": customer_id}`, or if that doesn't work then: `data: {"data": ["customer": customer_id]}`

Comment: Neither of those worked. On a side note, I changed $this->request->data to just $this->request, and data was part of that array, and it was empty. Also, Nowhere in there did I see anything pertaining to the values I'm sending.

Comment: Well, I ended up changing it to jquery's $.post and it worked. I don't understand why AJAX is giving me such trouble

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404576). You're data string probably isn't correct. Therefore CakePHP might not be able to put it in `$this->request->data`.

Comment: The use of `$this->request->data` indicates version 2.x, which handles the absence of the top-level data key. It's still useful to know about because it can at times act unexpectedly - e.g. if you submit `{foo: "bar", data: {Stuff: "zum"}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use print_r($this->request->params);

```
function finalize_payment($id = null){
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if($this->request->is('post')){ view
        print_r($this->request->params);
    } }
```